# MethodNotAllowedHttpException When i'm using Post Method [gloudemans-package]

Tags: php, laravel-5

recently I'm trying to create a shopping cart for my assignment project. I'm quite new to this framework, sorry if I asked something stupid :( It's a pleasure for me if you guys can check it for me. Tks

I'm also trying to switch to GET method but still didn't work

**The error were:**

```
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

**This is my controller**

```
public function cart() {

    if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
        $product_id = Request::get('product_id');
        $product = Product::find($product_id);
        Cart::add(array('id' => $product_id, 'name' => $product->name, 'qty' => 1, 'price' => $product->price));
    }
    if (Request::get('product_id') && (Request::get('increment')) == 1) {
        $rowId = Cart::search(array('id' => Request::get('product_id')));
        $item = Cart::get($rowId[0]);

        Cart::update($rowId[0], $item->qty + 1);
    }
    if (Request::get('product_id') && (Request::get('decrease')) == 1) {
        $rowId = Cart::search(array('id' => Request::get('product_id')));
        $item = Cart::get($rowId[0]);

        Cart::update($rowId[0], $item->qty - 1);
    }

    $cart = Cart::content();

    return view('cart', array('cart' => $cart, 'title' => 'Welcome', 'description' => '', 'page' => 'home'));}
```

This is my Route

```
Route::post('cart', 'HomepageController@cart')->name('cart');
```

**This is my view**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('cart')       
<section id="cart_items">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active">Shopping Cart</li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive cart_info">
            @if(count($cart))
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="cart_menu">
                        <td class="image">Item</td>
                        <td class="description"></td>
                        <td class="price">Price</td>
                        <td class="quantity">Quantity</td>
                        <td class="total">Total</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($cart as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cart_product">
                            <a href=""><img src="images/cart/one.png" alt=""></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_description">
                            <h4><a href="">{{$item->name}}</a></h4>
                            <p>Web ID: {{$item->id}}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_price">
                            <p>${{$item->price}}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_quantity">
                            <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                <a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a>
                                <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{$item->qty}}" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                <a class="cart_quantity_up" href='{{url("cart?product_id=$item->id&increment=1")}}'> + </a>
                                <a class="cart_quantity_down" href='{{url("cart?product_id=$item->id&decrease=1")}}'> - </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_total">
                            <p class="cart_total_price">${{$item->subtotal}}</p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cart_delete">
                            <a class="cart_quantity_delete" href=""><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @else
                <p>You have no items in the shopping cart</p>
                @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section> <!--/#cart_items-->
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `a` tags, this won't do a `POST` request, instead, the browser is gonna follow the link to make a `GET` request. That's why you are getting `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` since it's only expecting a `POST` request at that endpoint. The same issue will happen with the delete button you have.

This will be complicated to give you a complete solution in an answer. For what you are trying to do, there are several paths you can take to make this work.

- you can have a form(s) in your HTML to make a `POST` request and probably use buttons to post the increment and decrement the quantity, and/or delete, then reload the page with updated quantity.
- you can handle the increment/decrement/delete on the frontend using JS and updating the quantity field and finally submit the form with another button (e.g. Checkout Button).
  You can also, make this simpler using a framework like Vue/React to
  easily handle the cart behavior/function with reactivity.

Notes:

- you should not need to check `Request::isMethod('post')` if you only mapped it to `POST` in your routes. You should have 1 method per endpoint anyways.
- consider using `FormValidation` instead of explicitly checking if a value was sent or not https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation
- You might want to redirect to a `show` method after updating instead of returning a view.

### Example:

```html
<td class="cart_quantity">
  <div class="cart_quantity_button">
  <form action="{{ url('cart') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $item->id }}">

    <button type="submit" class="cart_quantity_up" name="increment"> + </button>

    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="{{$item->qty}}" autocomplete="off" size="2" readonly>

    <button type="submit" class="cart_quantity_down" href='{{url("cart?product_id=$item->id&=1")}}' name="decrease"> - </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: maybe take inspiration from https://www.larashout.com/laravel-e-commerce-application-development-shopping-cart, it's using a package but you can get an idea of the process flow.

Comment: i already wrap all the (a) tags u said into a form and using POST method, but it still didn't work
IMG here: https://imgur.com/t6bC3V2

Comment: where are your `increment`/`decrement` buttons?

Comment: I want to move slowly from step to step. So I decided to create a view first before moving to the next step (add, increase, decrease, delete) later.

Comment: view for what? I have added an example for your use case. this should replace the `td` of your button.